# Python / Matplotlib / plotting a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot following function with python.

```
fx =(x**4 - 7*x**3 + 15*x**2 - 21*x + 36) / (x**2-7*x+6)
```

When I plot it, using Matplotlib, it gives me this...

output python
[image: output python]

But according to Geogebra it should look like this.

output geogebra
[image: output geogebra]

Python code: (defined x as a sympy symbol above)

```
x = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
fx =(x**4 - 7*x**3 + 15*x**2 - 21*x + 36) / (x**2-7*x+6)

plt.plot(x,fx)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title('f(x)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I am new to using Matplotlib lib, so it could be something really stupid (o_o)... but I hope somebody can give me tip on how to solve it or help me out :)

Thank you!

"Solution"
[image: solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like its the same plot, but with different limit on the x and y axis.

You can set them using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` ([doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html))

in your case:

```
plt.xlim(-15, 15)
plt.ylim(-25, 25)
```

Comment: @itaishz 
except for the vertical lines connecting the two parts of the fucntion, the data in this area is the same

Comment: I don't think so? The asymptote at the matplotlib plot is at around x=6 while at the geogebra is at around x=1. And the curve approaches that asymptote from different directions at the two plots (meaning the positive side with respect to the asymptote goes to +inf in one plot and -inf in the other). [wolframalpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E4+-+7*x%5E3+%2B+15*x%5E2+-+21*x+%2B+36%29+%2F+%28x%5E2-7*x%2B6%29+where+x%3D-10+to+10+y%3D-25+to+25) proves geogebra plot is the correct one.

Comment: It worked! Looks like they are the same. Now I just need to get rid of the "vertical lines"... :) THANKS

Comment: I added a picture of the "correct" python plot.

Comment: @itaishz yeah it seem strange to me as well... those wiggles at x=1 in the matplotlib plot are also asymptotes - but they just don't look like they are in this graph because matplotlib doesn't draw them all the way for some reason

Comment: I guess matplotlib renders the plot such that it doesn't look like the correct plot when zooming-out.